# How to check if ObjCPropertyRefExpr is of type UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I'm able to retrieve the node ObjectiveCPropertyRefExpr out and I want to check if it's referring to something from the UITextField (in the future I want to check for other user input fields too).

Is there a way to check if the ObjectiveCPropertyRefExpr is from UITextField?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `ObjCPropertyRefExpr *expr`, you can do this

```
expr->getReceiverType(*Context).getAsString();
```

where `Context` is the `ASTContext`